Unix shell not passing CTRL+C signal to the running process
I have a multithreaded c++ programm.
The main thread does some setup and then creates several child processes, that handle incoming messages from a RabbitMQ. In the main thread there is a busy waiting solution:
  while (rmqbag_active) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
  }

Before I also register a signal handler for SIGINT:
  std::signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

void signal_handler([[maybe_unused]] int signal) {
  rmqbag_active = false;
  rmqbag::log_debug("Received stopping signal");
}

This also works fine when there is a low amount of work done in the child processes.
However, when the amount of messages received is too high (I don't know the exact threshold, but I the issue occurred when four child processes received about 1,750 messages per second) pressing CTRL+C doesn't do anything. The application doesn't receive a signal, as there is no logging output.
Now when I send SIGINT manually to the process using for example HTOP it gets processed correctly and the application stops normally.
I have tried this with multiple terminal emulators and the behavior seems the same for bash, zsh and fish shell.
I also tried different ways of implementing the busy wait solution by using for example nanosleep instead of this_thread::sleep_for.
Registering the signal handler for the child processes also didn't help.
I am confused as to how it is possible that the terminal I start the application in doesn't always send the user input to stop to the application.
HTOP is also just sending the signal and from there it gets processes, which indicates that it is not an issue with the code.
I should also mention that the child processes don't log anything, such that there is no message spam in the terminal.
Do you have an idea why the terminal isn't able to send a signal to the process?

Is calling rmqbag::log_debug from a signal handler legal? Is rmqbag_active atomic? Please show a [mre]

The problem is that signal handlers are very (very!) limited in what they are allowed to do: You can read the list here
For example, I am reasonably sure that this rmqbag::log_debug("Received stopping signal"); is undefined behavior.
Part of the problem, as far as I understand it, is that there is no way for you to know or control which thread executes the signal handler, and that just leads to either an extremely limited set of legal actions or a huge set of more or less janky edge cases (aka UB) which seems to be what you experience.
There is a solution though (probably several, but this is what I use). By using a set of POSIX functions you can control where the signals are handled, and thus ensure that it happens in a context these restrictions do not apply.
The first step is to turn off signals for your main thread, and you should do this as one of the first things - at least before you spawn any other threads, since they inherit the signal mask from their parent.
// Before any other thread is started
sigset_t set;
sigemptyset(&set);
sigaddset(&set, SIGINT); // The one you want
sigaddset(&set, SIGTERM); // But you can add more if you want
sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
sigaddset(&set, SIGCHLD);
int err = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, nullptr);
if (err != 0)
    std::cout << "Error setting up signal handler" << std::endl;

Then you need a thread specifically for handling signals - in my case I spawn a new one.
// Note: Pass on exactly the set of signals that you just turned off
auto signalHandler = std::thread(sigHandler, &set);

The signal handler thread then calls sigwait with the set of signals you want to receive, this is a blocking call so the signal thread cannot do much else.
void sigHandler(sigset_t const *const set)
{
    int sig; // Used as output variable

    while (true)
    {
        sigwait(set, &sig);

        switch (sig) // Examine which signal wait received
        {
        case SIGINT:
            // Handle the signal
            rmqbag_active = false;
            rmqbag::log_debug("Received stopping signal");
            break;
        case SIGTERM:
            // Other cases here to illustrate
            // Do stuff
            return;
        case SIGUSR1:
            break;
        case SIGCHLD:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

All of this ensures that the signals you select will be handled specifically in the signalHandler thread and nowhere else, additionally they will be handled in "normal" code and not in some interrupt-ish context where you are not allowed to do anything.
You can read more here:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigwait.3.html


Looks like good analysis of the problem and a good answer to me. However I personally wouldn't use a new thread for signal handling, I'd use the main thread. Also busy waiting is terribly bad practice, luckily it can (and IMO should) be fixed as part of this story. Replace it with a pselect() or ppoll() that atomically enables SIGINT delivery only for the duration of that wait. The signal handler function should do one thing only: flip a boolean. Upon returning from pselect() the main thread would check for that boolean and if set then execute whatever you really want to do on a SIGINT.

@egmont I am confused, what is the difference between waiting on a sigwait call vs. waiting on a pselect or ppoll call?

But yes, instead of spawning a new thread you could let the main thread call sigHandler (in this example) as the last thing it does if it has nothing else to do.

Your exact example looks fine to me, but as soon as you begin to stretch things, you can encounter all sorts of race conditions. E.g. what if you want to handle any signal where you'd continue that loop, and SIGINT is delivered exactly when you're handling that other signal? Your SIGINT would be lost. pselect not only gives you atomic unblocking of the signal, but also allows to combine with other input sources (wait for signal or timeout or input on a file descriptor or incoming network connection). pselect scales to more complex scenarios, sigwait doesn't. Plus saves a thread.

Here is a link to the POSIX standard for sigwait: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigwait.html and here is a quote: "The sigwait() function shall select a pending signal from set, atomically clear it from the system's set of pending signals, and return that signal number in the location referenced by sig". Again, I struggle to see what your point is and where pselect is so much better - perhaps if you made an answer and showed how you would do this it would be more illustrative?

I'm terribly sorry but I have no time or motivation to do that; there are millions of examples out there showing it. I'm not trying to convince you, I'm trying to help OP towards a better solution. As I've mentioned, there's nothing wrong in your current code, but if you try to add new features (let's say handle SIGWINCH but continue the loop) you can no longer do it without race condition and risking losing a signal if you stick with sigwait, since the signal can be delivered (and thus ignored) while the code is outside of that sigwait call. That is what pselect fixes.
